# How avoid negative numbers during datediff

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have table where have time like : 15:30 , want select data from table in 15 minute interval but only possitive, I try :

```
select id from myTbl
where type = 2 and DATEDIFF(mi,my_time,LEFT(CAST(GETDATE() as time),5)) <= 15
```

For example if my_time = 15:55  and `LEFT(CAST(GETDATE() as time),5)) = 16:45` in response i have -50 and its <= 15 but i need comparison only possitive , when i try ABS it dont help me because when time in response is -14 ABS take it +14 and its <=15 . So i have 28 minute interval (-14 and 14). Is it possible tu avoid all negative numbers ? and comparison only if it is possitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select id 
from myTbl
where type = 2 
      and DATEDIFF(mi,my_time,LEFT(CAST(GETDATE() as time),5)) <= 15 
      and DATEDIFF(mi,my_time,LEFT(CAST(GETDATE() as time),5)) >=0
```

Comment: @M.Ali's answer is better

Answer (score 4):

A much better approach would be some thing like ...

```
SELECT id 
FROM myTbl
WHERE [TYPE] = 2 
AND my_time >= CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETDATE()) AS TIME)
AND my_time <= CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)
```

Avoid using DATEDIFF and other scalar functions on your columns in where clause, as it will not allow query optimizer to make use of any indexes even if there is an index that query can benefit from ,   Read this article for more information [`SARGable functions in SQL Server`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: It's not the use of functions in the where clause that's the death knell for sargability, but rather the use of functions against a value (i.e. column) from the table.

Comment: Ben I this is exactly what I have said, Since OP is using a scalar function in where clause in this scenario thats why I specifically mentioned WHERE clause in my explanation :)

Comment: I missed the "on your columns", which changes the tone considerably. But you're absolutely correct. Sorry!